# Java error on android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

i am new to android app developing i am following buckys tutorials
currently i am on this part
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdOxtws4DsI&index=13&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBsvRxJJOzG4r4k_zLKrnxl
i did everything as told but when i run the app i find this error here's my logcat

```
12-08 20:42:45.548 2465-2465/com.kimdevelopment.kimmmm I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
12-08 20:42:45.549 2465-2465/com.kimdevelopment.kimmmm I/art: Late-enabling JIT
12-08 20:42:45.552 2465-2465/com.kimdevelopment.kimmmm I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
12-08 20:42:45.630 2465-2465/com.kimdevelopment.kimmmm W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.kimdevelopment.kimmmm-1/lib/x86
12-08 20:42:45.696 2465-2465/com.kimdevelopment.kimmmm D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-08 20:42:45.696 2465-2465/com.kimdevelopment.kimmmm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.kimdevelopment.kimmmm, PID: 2465
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kimdevelopment.kimmmm/com.kimdevelopment.kimmmm.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:98)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:91)
    at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.<init>(ToolbarActionBar.java:73)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:205)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:99)
    at com.kimdevelopment.kimmmm.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-08 20:42:54.014 2465-2465/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2465 SIG: 9
```

also here's the java file that i edited

```
package com.kimdevelopment.kimmmm;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout kimsLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        Button redButton = new Button(this);
        kimsLayout.addView(redButton);
        setContentView(kimsLayout);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and finally the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.kimdevelopment.kimmmm.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: better than adding a link to another topic which is not my same problem you can just help if you can.

Comment: it is the same problem. you need to read the error, figure out what is null, and figure out why it is null. which is what is explained in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have an element in your XML that references the toolbar. You need an element with an ID "toolbar" maybe like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.kimdevelopment.kimmmm.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/windowContentOverlay"
        app:theme="@style/Toolbar"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT:

Also, with these lines, you are setting the `Activity` content to something besides your XML defined layout:

```
    RelativeLayout kimsLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    Button redButton = new Button(this);
    kimsLayout.addView(redButton);
    setContentView(kimsLayout);
```

You should change your XML main `RelativeLayout` and give it an id (like the elements within it) and then set the content view like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
```

Comment: but i didnt add or remove anything that can cause this i am using the Noactionbar theme,also i tried it and i still get the error

Comment: I edited my response... hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used tool bars that much so I could be off, but you're instantiating your tool bar with a R.id which usually corresponds to an XML element.

Comment: little more explanation please?:D